# ValueAnimator getAnimatedValue not working as expected

Tags: java, android

I have a simple ValueAnimator code. But values from `getAnimatedValue` ​​are irrelevant than I expected.

```
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 3);
int mDuration = 3000; //in millis
va.setDuration(mDuration);
va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        int value = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        Log.v(TAG, "::" + value);
    }
});
va.setRepeatCount(2);
va.start();
```

LOG:

```
2021-06-01 11:26:06.410 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:06.423 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:06.916 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:06.934 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:07.163 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:07.181 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:07.304 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:07.322 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:07.551 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:07.567 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:07.585 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:07.602 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:07.919 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:07.937 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:08.078 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:08.095 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:08.114 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:08.236 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:08.254 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:08.922 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:08.940 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:09.414 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:09.432 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:09.625 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:09.642 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:09.926 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:09.944 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:10.594 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:10.611 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:10.927 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:10.945 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:11.244 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:11.261 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:11.929 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:11.947 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:12.160 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:12.175 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:12.423 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:12.443 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:12.936 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:12.950 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:13.586 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::0
2021-06-01 11:26:13.602 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:13.935 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:13.953 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:13.972 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:13.989 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:14.234 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::1
2021-06-01 11:26:14.252 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:14.938 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:14.955 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:14.973 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:15.412 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::2
2021-06-01 11:26:15.430 9609-9609/com.sample.animationtest V/MainActivity: ::3
```

But the values I expected:
0, 1, 2, 3,
0, 1, 2, 3
Stop